# Fading out multiple objects in pyQT

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I'm trying to fade out an entire row of a GridLayout when a user clicks a button. So far I've been able to loop each of the widgets on the specific row which is working but I'm struggling with creating a parallel animation for them all...

```
    idx = self.parent().findChild(QGridLayout).indexOf(self)
    location = self.parent().findChild(QGridLayout).getItemPosition(idx)
    row, col = location[:2]
    self.parent_grid = self.parent().findChild(QGridLayout)
    col_count = self.parent().findChild(QGridLayout).columnCount()
    print(col_count)
    self.effects = []
    self.animations = []
    anim_group = QParallelAnimationGroup()
    for i in range(col_count-1):
        effect = QGraphicsOpacityEffect(self)
        self.effects.append(effect)
        self.parent_grid.itemAtPosition(row,i).widget().setGraphicsEffect(effect)
        new_anim = QPropertyAnimation(effect, b"opacity")
        new_anim.setDuration(1000)
        new_anim.setStartValue(1)
        new_anim.setEndValue(0)
        new_anim.finished.connect(lambda: self.hide_widget(col_count, row))
        self.animations.append(new_anim)
        anim_group.addAnimation(new_anim)

    anim_group.start()
```

Comment: I don't understand, what is the problem with the code above? Do you want to set the animation for the whole grid or just the row? Why don't you just add the widgets of that row to a container with a horizontal layout? You also created no reference for the animation group, so it will be probably destroyed. Besides, accessing the parent contents and properties is rarely a good thing, especially if done like that.

Comment: I didn't know what the problem with the code above was either... hence me posting here :) It was that I hadn't created a ref for the QParallelAnimationGroup so thanks for spotting that! RE your other Qs/points - It's a todo list "mark complete" clickable label I'm coding so I want to fade out the current row/Todo only, grid seemed most appropriate as I need to sort by columns and will have multiple columns so the alignment grids offered was favourable. Noted on accessing parent contents/properties, it's also a pain to do! Any suggestions welcome on other ways to approach would be welcome!

Comment: Well, I don't know about your layout, but since you need to change the opacity of all widgets in each row, here's an idea: create a QObject subclass to group all widgets of each row and automatically create QGraphicsOpacityEffects to each widget, then add a custom `pyqtProperty` for the opacity and a related *setter* that would set the opacity to each QGraphicsEffect of those widgets. The result would be conceptually similar, but with the benefit of just using *one* animation for each row, which will directly set the opacity of each widget, instead of multiple Qt animations for each of them.

Comment: Sounds like a better approach.. unfortunately a little beyond my skills at this point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the count of widgets might be high, it's not a good idea to create an animation for each one of them.

Instead, you can use a "controller" that has its own unique animation, and updates the opacity of each widgets in its row.

While using a QPropertyAnimation can work, it would require adding a custom property for that, and it's not really needed for this purpose. Instead, use a basic QVariantAnimation and connect its [`valueChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariantanimation.html#valueChanged) to a function that updates the opacity of each graphics effect.

Here is a possible implementation:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class RowFadeController(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent, buttons):
        super().__init__()
        self.buttons = buttons
        self.effects = []
        for button in buttons:
            effect = QGraphicsOpacityEffect(button, opacity=1.0)
            button.setGraphicsEffect(effect)
            self.effects.append(effect)

        self.animation = QVariantAnimation(self)
        self.animation.setStartValue(1.)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0.)
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.setOpacity)

    def toggle(self, hide):
        self.animation.setDirection(
            self.animation.Forward if hide else self.animation.Backward
        )
        self.animation.start()

    def setOpacity(self, opacity):
        for effect in self.effects:
            effect.setOpacity(opacity)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.fadeControllers = []
        for row in range(10):
            rowButtons = []
            for col in range(10):
                button = QPushButton(str(col + 1))
                layout.addWidget(button, row, col)
                rowButtons.append(button)

            toggleButton = QPushButton('toggle', checkable=True)
            layout.addWidget(toggleButton, row, layout.columnCount() - 1)

            fadeController = RowFadeController(self, rowButtons)
            self.fadeControllers.append(fadeController)
            toggleButton.clicked.connect(fadeController.toggle)

app = QApplication([])
test = Window()
test.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: This is awesome - so much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Tweaked for PyQT6 and added a function to get rid of the row once it's faded out.

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

class RowFadeController(QObject):
    def __init__(self, parent, buttons):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.buttons = buttons
        self.effects = []
        for button in buttons:
            effect = QGraphicsOpacityEffect(button, opacity=1.0)
            button.setGraphicsEffect(effect)
            self.effects.append(effect)

        self.animation = QVariantAnimation(self)
        self.animation.setStartValue(1.)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0.)
        self.animation.valueChanged.connect(self.setOpacity)
        self.animation.finished.connect(self.hideRow)

    def toggle(self, hide):
        self.animation.setDirection(
            self.animation.Direction.Forward if hide else self.animation.Direction.Backward
        )
        self.animation.start()

    def setOpacity(self, opacity):
        for effect in self.effects:
            effect.setOpacity(opacity)

    def hideRow(self):
        for button in self.buttons:
            button.hide()
            button.setParent(None)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.fadeControllers = []
        for row in range(10):
            rowButtons = []
            for col in range(10):
                button = QPushButton(str(col + 1))
                layout.addWidget(button, row, col)
                rowButtons.append(button)

            toggleButton = QPushButton('toggle', checkable=True)
            rowButtons.append(toggleButton)
            layout.addWidget(toggleButton, row, layout.columnCount() - 1)

            fadeController = RowFadeController(self, rowButtons)
            self.fadeControllers.append(fadeController)
            toggleButton.clicked.connect(fadeController.toggle)

app = QApplication([])
test = Window()
test.show()
app.exec()
```